# How to find a dict in a list with a particular key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists with dicts as below:

```
[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test1'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}]
[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test1'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'Get'}]
[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}]
```

for this list I would like to get the lists if keys `Platform` and  `Name` are present.
So I would like to get
`[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test1'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}]`
and `[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}]`

I don't know how to achieve this in one most effective way?
I did a very simplistic way which is working, but in the future, if the list count grows then it might take a longer time. Is there any simple and effective way to achieve this?

```
for arr_keys in arr:
    if arr_keys['key'] == "Platform":
        platform = arr_keys['value']
    if arr_keys['key'] == "Name":
        Name = arr_keys['value']
```

Comment: Why `[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test1'}]` and not `{'Platform': 'Test', 'Name': 'Test1'}`?

Comment: I know, it's pretty confusing the guys who was earlier did like this, so can't change...I have to work on this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So for each list, you want to check if ***all*** the keys (Platform and Name) appear in ***any*** of the dicts. This directly translates to:

```py
lists = [[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test1'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}],
         [{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test1'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'Get'}],
         [{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'Test2'}, {'key': 'APICall', 'value': 'post'}]]

for obj in lists:
    if all(any(d["key"] == key for d in obj) for key in ("Platform", "Name")):
        print(obj)
```

This will however iterate over the dicts for each key. To do it in one pass over the dicts, something like this can work, using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

keys = ("Platform", "Name")
for obj in lists:
    seen = defaultdict(bool)
    for d in obj:
        seen[d["key"]] = True

    if all(seen[key] for key in keys):
        print(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only improvement you can make without changing the formatting of the input is to break out of the loop once the keys 'Platform' and 'Name' are encountered.

```
platform = None
name = None
for arr_keys in arr:
    if arr_keys['key'] == "Platform":
        platform = arr_keys['value']
    if arr_keys['key'] == "Name":
        name = arr_keys['value']
    if platform is not None and name is not None:
        print(arr)
        break
```